# A function to append a character in a string efficiently

Tags: c, arrays, string, append

How can I improve this function in regard to speed :

```
void chrapp (char arr[], char chr, int pos)
{
    memmove(arr + pos + 1, arr + pos, strlen(arr + pos));
    *(arr + pos + 1) = chr;
}
```

---

Also, it unfortunately doesn't work with appending a character to the very beginning of the **array**, which is also a rein for improvement.

Comment: Performance aside, part of the reason this doesn't work reliably is the failure to also move the terminator.

Comment: Try `memmove(arr + pos + 1, arr + pos, strlen(arr + pos) + 1);` so you copy the null as well.

Comment: And `*(arr + pos) = chr;`, not `*(arr + pos + 1) = chr;` -- you need to write to the space you opened up, not the char after it.

Comment: Ah yes. The array is not guaranteed to be filled of `\0`s

Comment: Always measure the effect of low-level changes/optimizations like this; and try different compiler optimizations. It's very easy to make wrong assumptions with current advanced compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [@Dmitri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929459/dmitri) comment to include the null terminator `'\0'` in the move and `*(arr + pos)` rather than `*(arr + pos + 1)`.

```
void chrapp(char arr[], char chr, int pos) {
  memmove(arr + pos + 1, arr + pos, strlen(arr + pos) + 1);
  *(arr + pos) = chr;
}
```

There are other issues:

1. Memory management: For now, assume the space exist.
2. Detecting when `pos` is past end of the string.  In this case, simply append.  Without this test, code results would be disastrous.  At this point easy enough to add the string size to the function signature and check it (not shown).
3. Detecting when `pos` is at the end of the string.  Since code knowns the string length, do the same as #2.  It is reasonable to handle the simple append case in a special fashion to speed-up the function as it is certainly common.
4. Use better types.  `size_t`, rather `int`.  `int` instead of `char` - typically as fast or faster and it is certainly more idiomatic.
5. String functions often return the string address.
6. `char == '\0'` should have special handling.  Existing code works except the shift is not needed.  A shift, which writes an additional null character which is not needed.

...

```
char *chrapp2(char arr[], int chr, size_t pos) {
  size_t len = strlen(arr);
  if (pos < len) {
    // shift right
    memmove(arr + pos + 1, arr + pos, len - pos + 1);
    *(arr + pos) = chr;
  } else {
    arr[len] = chr;  // Over-write \0
    arr[len+1] = '\0';
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: is there a better way (especially faster) of appending a character ? This was the fastest one __I__ could come up with but you seem quite informed of appending so you might know better solutions(s).

Comment: If code all ready knows 1) the length of the string 2) The new index is not pass the end 3) the character is not `\0` 4) space is available, then fastest is: `memmove(arr + pos + 1, arr + pos, len - pos + 1); *(arr + pos) = chr;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code is going through the string twice. Once for calculating the length of the string and the second time for moving it. You can do it in one loop, however considering that the standard library functions are implemented in highly optimized manner it is not sure it will actually speed up things. Try the following code:

```
void chrapp (char arr[], char chr, int pos) {
  char *s;
  char cc;
  for(s=arr+pos; *s; s++) {
     cc = *s; *s = chr; chr = cc;
  }
  *s++ = chr;
  *s = 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Doing it in one loop sounds like an optimization to me.